Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook')
I have project, build with nuxt v2, but now i upgrade it to v3, but when i want to yarn build, build crashed.
My code


// --- Main Nuxt.js module ---
module.exports = function nuxtBootstrapVue(moduleOptions = {}) {
  this.nuxt.hook('build:before', () => {
    // Merge moduleOptions with default
    const options = {
      ...this.options.bootstrapVue,
      ...moduleOptions
    }



Error in Console:


ERROR  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook')
 at nuxtBootstrapVue (node_modules/bootstrap-vue/nuxt/index.js:34:13)



i checked nuxt version and NuxtBootstrapVue version, and its compatible.

Using screenshots is not very helpful when formulating a question. It is difficult to reproduce your issue, so fewer people will engage with the question. It's worth posting the code in textual form within a code block. Later on, search engines will also be better able to interpret the content of the question.

Thanks for your comment, i edited it! i hope someone will help me solve this.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534527/how-do-i-start-websocket-server-socketio-or-otherwise-in-nuxt-3-does-not-work
